# Can I create and interpolant using e.g. scipy griddata?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am converting a matlab script to a python script where I use the function scatteredInterpolant(). In matlab it has the nice property that it creates an interpolant that I can evaluate at few selected points a lot faster than creating the interpolated griddata over the whole domain. From the matlab manual it says:

```
% Fast to create interpolant F and evaluate multiple times
F = scatteredInterpolant(X,Y,V)
v1 = F(Xq1,Yq1)
v2 = F(Xq2,Yq2)

% Slower to compute interpolations separately using griddata
v1 = griddata(X,Y,V,Xq1,Yq1)
v2 = griddata(X,Y,V,Xq2,Yq2)
```

So far I have only found a python alternative to the latter approach and it takes approximatly the same time no matter how many points i evaluate the interpolant at:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example surface
[theta, phi] = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, 100),
    np.linspace(np.spacing(1), np.pi/2-np.pi/20, 100))
x = 1.0*np.multiply(np.cos(theta), np.sin(phi))
y = 1.0*np.multiply(np.sin(theta), np.sin(phi))
z = 1.0 * np.cos(phi)


[xi, yi] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 10),
                       np.linspace(-1, 1, 10))
%timeit zi = griddata((np.reshape(x, -1), np.reshape(y, -1)), np.reshape(z, -1), (xi, yi), method='linear')
%timeit zi_singlepoint = griddata((np.reshape(x, -1), np.reshape(y, -1)), np.reshape(z, -1), (0.0, 0.0), method='linear')
```

Is it possible to get an interpolant that can be evaluated as in matlab using the griddata() function in scipy or other module in python?

EDIT: I just found that functions based on scipy.interpolate.BivariateSpline works in a similar fasion to matlabs scatteredinterpolant(). From the documentation:
"*The BivariateSpline class is the 2-dimensional analog of the UnivariateSpline class. It and its subclasses implement the FITPACK functions described above in an object oriented fashion, **allowing objects to be instantiated that can be called to compute the spline value by passing in the two coordinates as the two arguments.***" I will try this out and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the interpolations methods that can be called and evaluated with given coordinates are:

```
scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline
scipy.interpolate.Rbf
scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator
scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator
scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator
```